# Removing duplicate/opposite entries in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have a sheet containing the following data:
URL A, URL B, similar score in percent.

If URL A is 98% similar to URL B, it means that URL B is 98% similar to URL A, and listed as well.

I want to find and eliminate these duplicates/reversed entries. For now, I have tried having two extra columns concatenating URL A+URL B in one, and URL B+URL A in one. This way I have unique identifiers.

After this I'm kinda stuck, because I'm dealing with a lot of variables, as data is in two different rows, and two different columns. I might be looking into a script, taking the A+B value, iterating through the B+A value until it finds a match, and somehow marks this (or simply just deletes it), since my knowledge of formulas for highlighting these duplicates are falling short.

This sheet shows the concept - the first 100 rows (it's about 11K in total): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YKsguAn1lYjV4FlP_6_TlKGvFcpFAEzn7bpAyOEmozQ/edit?usp=sharing

Any suggestions for what I should look into?

Comment: Your requirements are a bit unclear. Please show your _hand-entered_ expected results in the sample spreadsheet. Show just enough of data that is required to illustrate what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for answering. That is because I don't know what a smart output would be. I could have an output for each row stating the row that is duplicate/reversed, but on the other hand - the end result should be that all duplicates are removed.

The issue can be looked up, looking at row 3-4-5-6, where only two would remain, or it should state in row 3 that it is similar to row 5.

Comment: Consider providing more details about this? How do you come up with the similarity rate? And why is it necessary for finding duplicates?

Comment: The similarity rate is given in the data dump, and not that relevant here. It is necessary to remove the opposite duplicates, because I need to go through all similar pages, and give an action on what to do with them. The action for A is similar to b, is the same as when B is similar to A. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a solution where I sorted by URL A and implemented this formula:

```
=IF(A2<B2,A2&B2,B2&A2)
```

This way I had the concatenation the same way for the real one and the opposite. I didn't know you could use "<" on strings.

After this, I could delete duplicated values in the column with the formula above.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `filter(match())` pattern to find duplicate values, like this:

```
=unique( 
  flatten( 
    filter( 
      A2:B, 
      match(A2:A & B2:B, B2:B & A2:A, 0), 
      C2:C >= 90 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: This seems like a great suggestion, however I don't know whether the result is true, but it seems to be correct. I don't know how to check this, besides knowing that the result would be slightly higher than 50 % of the rows, which match.

What I then need, is the "similar to" URL, but I guess I could use a vlookup for that.